# Is it possible to restrict account creation with MediaWiki using an access code?

Tags: mediawiki

My organization is running a wiki which we want anyone to be able to view, and ~200 people to be able to edit. It's currently based on MediaWiki.

The wiki software gitit has the ability to allow those and only those with the access code to create an account. Is there a way to implement this with MediaWiki? The idea is we just want to send a mass email to everyone with the access code, and they can choose to make an account. Ideally we could also change the access code in the future if spammers get their hands on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [InviteSignup](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:InviteSignup) extension does that. It can be also configured in such a way that everyone can register but only people with invites get the permissions to edit articles.